# How to make this program go back to prompt until the user exits

Tags: java

While writing code for my program I thought of testing the first part before moving on and writing the operations. Although I have the user input, but I want the options to be displayed after each operation (add, deltete..) is done untill the users presses exit. How do I modify my code to do it?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Records {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        do {
            System.out.println("1.Add \n 2.Delete \n 3.Update \n 4.Show \n Exit");
            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            //int choice;
            System.out.println("Enter your Choice : ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            choice = sc.nextInt();

            switch (choice) {
                case 1: 
                    System.out.println("Getting ready to Add a Record ");
                    //set();
                    break;

                case 2: 
                    System.out.println("Getting ready to Delete a Record ");
                    //delete();
                    break;

                case 3: 
                    System.out.println("Getting ready to Update a Record ");
                    //update();
                    break;

                case 4: 
                    System.out.println("Here is your record ");
                    //display();
                    break;

                case 5: 
                    System.out.println("Out we go.");
                    System.exit(0);
                    //exit();
                    break;

                default: 
                    System.out.println("Try again");
                    break;
            }
        } while ( choice > 5 || choice < 1 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change your while condition to:

```
} while ( choice > 0 && choice < 5 );
```

Comment: But will this condition, consider the `default` case in any way. Won't this still break the loop, after printing "Try again"!!!!

Comment: @nIcEcOw makes sense and of course the condition can be changed to `while (choice != 5)` - depends on what the OP wants.

Comment: I think This will exit the program if user enters valid/invalid  input but OP wants prompt for the input after single operation.

Comment: @TAsk it won't exit on valid input (unless it's 5 which is meant for exit). As for invalid input - see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

> Although I have the user input, but I want the options to be displayed
>   after each operation (add, deltete..) is done **untill the users presses
>   exit.**

You can set `int flag=0;` and when user selects exit option set flag to 1 to tell loop to exit.As of now you are already breaking out for number `> 5` or `< 1` in `default case` so no need to put that condition in `while`.

```
int flag=0;//Declare outside the loop
do{
...
   case 5: System.out.println("Out we go.");
           flag=1;//Set flag to 1 if user enters 5
           break;
...
} while ( flag!=1 );//Exit the loop when flag==1
//Or directly  while ( choice!=5 );
```

---

**Serious EDIT**

As Java Programmer I should probably suggest you to use `boolean` primitive type for flagging.

```
boolean flag=true;//Declare outside the loop
do{
...
   case 5: System.out.println("Out we go.");
           flag=false;//Set flag to 1 if user enters 5
           break;
...
} while (flag);//Exit the loop when flag==false
```

One More thing:

Surround code with `try-catch` to leave out invalid inputs and prompt again for input.
Most of the times it's not recommended to swallow the `Exception`.

```
do{
 try{
  ....//Your Switch case
 }catch(InputMismatchException e){}
} while (choice !=5);//But remove System.exti(0); from your switch statement
```

Comment: @nIcEcOw cause he's a c/c++ programmer :P

Comment: Because I love integer more than boolean ;) Never mind boolean should be used.As it just provide flagging nothing more than that.

Comment: Ahha, since I too use to put integers for this thingy, though I always wanted myself to change to boolean for this behaviour, +! though to all :-)

Comment: @TAsk so stop acting like one! be a proud Java programmer and use boolean/Boolean for binary flags! :D

Comment: @TAsk: My bad, actually, when it comes to size, I just learned, [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), says it's size is something that is not precisely defined. So still confused on that front :(

Comment: Actually, if to be serious, I don't see the need for `flag` at all: either exit like the user did originally or a simple `return` are two good options that allow you to do: `while(true)`. And @nIcEcOw - it's not always about size :P

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your scanner really has an int, use `sc.hasNextInt()` to validate the user entered a number. To end the do/while loop at "5.Exit", just have it like `do{...}while(choice!=5)`. Code below is not tested.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Records {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        do {
            System.out.println("1.Add \n 2.Delete \n 3.Update \n 4.Show \n 5.Exit");
            System.out.println("Enter your Choice : ");
            choice = -1;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            // validate the next thing in your scanner is an int
            // otherwise, sc.nextInt() might cause an exception
            if (sc.hasNextInt()){
                choice = sc.nextInt();
                switch (choice) {
                    case 1: System.out.println("Getting ready to Add a Record ");
                    // ...
                    break;

                    case 2: System.out.println("Getting ready to Delete a Record ");
                    // ...
                    break;

                    case 3: System.out.println("Getting ready to Update a Record ");
                    // ...
                    break;

                    case 4: System.out.println("Here is your record ");
                    // ...
                    break;

                    case 5: System.out.println("Out we go.");
                    // skip System.exit(0), your main method ends 
                    // automatically when you leave your do/while loop
                    break;

                    default: System.out.println("Try again");
                    break;
                } 
            }
        // if choice == 5 it ends, otherwise, starts over...
        } while ( choice != 5 );
    }

}
```

Comment: Though I upvoted this, but still I am amazed, why the person who is answering, never did looked at what the OP is doing wrong, in their code. What is the need to create a new reference to the `Scanner` object with each iteration of the `do-while` loop? Why not keep that part outside that thingy? Just a bit curious :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw and also: why this code will never enter the `if` condition ?

Comment: @alfasin: Ahha, I missed that part totally, since there is nothing for `Scanner` in every run :-) I won't answer today, seems like my head is not looking at these thingies today, so I might can give bad advice :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw I have days like this too, may the force be with your thingies!

Answer (score -1):

Simply make your while loop as:

```
} while ( choice!=0 );(The Wrong one)
```

Correction:

```
} while(choice!=0 && choice<=5)
```

Comment: -1 since you arrived so late to the party, you should at least bother  to read the question thoroughly as well as the already published answers.

Comment: @alfasin This -1 doesn't bother me, and for arriving late here, So i just woke up half an hour ago and just seen this question.So

Comment: @AmiteshRai: Please, do reconsider this answer again. Why two values to exit the loop (`5`(it also closes the app, forcibly) and `0`)?